# How to parse a nested JSON available in a Hive/Hbase column using spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

How to parse and flatten a nested JSON available in a Hive/Hbase column using spark scala?

Example:

```
A hive table is having a column "c1" with following json

{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red",
    "Lines": [{
            "LineNumber": 1,
            "Text": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "LineNumber": 2,
            "Text": "123"
        }
     ]
}

I want to parse this json and create a dataframe to contain columns and values like this
+------+------+-------+------------+------+
|fruit | size | color | LineNumber | Text |
+------+------+-------+------------+------+
|Apple | Large| Red   | 1          | ABC  |
|Apple | Large| Red   | 2          | 123  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------+
```

Appreciate any thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json to String using mkstring and then use following code

val otherFruitRddRDD = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(
"""{"Fruitname":"Jack","fruitDetails":{"fruit":"Apple","size":"Large"}}""" :: Nil)

val otherFruit = spark.read.json(otherFruitRddRDD)

otherFruit.show()

Answer (score 0):

```
 val df = spark.read.json("example.json")
```

You can find detail examples on following link

- https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html

Comment: It's a nested json inside a dataframe column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a method like this :

```
df.select(from_json($"c1", schema))
```

schema will be Struct Type and will contain the structure of the
json for you it will be  a.Fruit b.size c.color

Comment: I tried from_json but it's a nested json and "from_json" is increasing complexity when we want to parse each element and create a schema for each element in the json.

Comment: you can try a jackson complex json parser and use the json column as a String in a UDF and flatten it